# How to listen to (or intercept) all changes to EclipseLink JPA L2 Cache , incl. through Cache Coordination?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

The goal is to the have all clustered application servers recognizing any change to the data of a certain cached database table, so that the application code can react on it. I am using eclipselink with cache coordination. The database table is cached using standard eclipselink cache (@Cache).

I am aware of the possibility to use database triggers, but since all changes to the data are through the app only, I would prefer a solution without touching the database. I have tried  [CacheInterceptor](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_cacheinterceptor.htm) but it doesn't seem to catch data updates events.

I have thought about [JPA Entity Life Cycle Events](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event) but that doesn't seem to catch Cache Coordination events.

Another option would be to intercept the JMS Cache Coordination queue, but that feels more like a workaround.

What is the best practice solution to this problem? Please provide concrete configuration hints.

Comment: EclipseLink's cache coordination is intended for this purpose, why is it a workaround?  Are you looking at listening for only local changes or something else?

Comment: The way I did set up EclipseLink cache coordination, it does automatically notify itself of changes and invalidate the caches correspondingly. Which is working fine. But I am looking for a way to have my own application code notified of changes (in addition to automatic invalidation of the cache internally). My question is how can I properly intercept (or get notified) of the cache coordination messages without having to add an own listener (and interpreter) of the JMS message queue. I was hoping for something like a "L2CacheInvalidationListener" that could be registered somewhere.

Comment: see https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/814594/

Comment: Thanks Chris, so I will try postDistributedMergeUnitOfWorkChangeSet, postMergeUnitOfWorkChangeSet of SessionEventListener